# Using jquery import https://cdn1.singteldigital.com/etc/clientlibs/granite/jquery.min.js creating issue for existing functionalities

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am importing the below jquery script but if I import from below source, my existing functionalities (action call) are not working properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/clientlibs/granite/jquery.min.js">script
```

If I remove "src="/etc/clientlibs/granite/jquery.min.js"", everything will work fine but my required pop up display function (newly added) wont work. So please let me know the alternate/equivalent import for "/etc/clientlibs/granite/jquery.min.js"

JS to be used:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
}
```

Comment: What is the error in console you getting ?

Comment: Down load the file and add it to your code base, then use that path. Also your jQuery code seems to be bit messed up.

Comment: @VinodLouis: In console there is no error but my existing functionality is not called when i import the jquery.min.js

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan: Tried by copying jquery.min.js to my code base, still same issue.

Comment: Your new js may be conflicting with existing js.You can use noConflict function for that. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/